# sed replace ' with \'

Tags: bash, sed

This:

```
echo "Hel'lo" | sed s/\'/\\\'/g
```

Yields

```
Hel'lo
```

What I want is this:

```
Hel\'lo
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
echo "Hel'lo" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"
Hel\'lo
```

Also

```
echo "Hel'lo" |  sed s/\'/\\\\\'/g
```

Comment: Actually, your first example has an unnecessary extra backslash.  In the replacement string, since the `'` isn't being treated as a special, you don't need to escape it.  `sed "s/'/\\'/g"`

Answer (score 1):

Or without quoting the sed argument:

```
echo "Hel'lo" | sed s/\'/\\\\\'/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with all single quotes:

```
echo "Hel'lo" | sed 's/'\''/\\'\''/g'
```

And since your question is also tagged <kbd>bash</kbd>, I might as well point out that you don't even need sed:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ foo="Hel'lo"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "${foo/\'/\'}"
Hel\'lo
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Hel'lo" | sed 's/'\''/\\&/'
```